# Абсолютно спозиционированная обертка на изображение высоты 100% в Firefox

Tags: css, вёрстка, кроссбраузерность

Всем привет.

Нужна очень сложная структура чего-то типа плитки товара. Сверстать получается, но разваливается в Firefox. Прошу совета. Спасибо!

Плитка товара должна быть пропорциональна: менять высоту в зависимости от ширины. Зададим эту пропорциональность через `padding-bottom: 50%;`

Внутри, соответственно, абсолютно спозиционированный контекст:

```
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

Получаем нужный пропорционально меняющийся контекст: https://jsfiddle.net/u7ab3ezo/

Картинка внутри должна быть 100% высоты этого контейнера и центрироваться. Делаем тег `img` с `height: 100%;` и пока что тоже все ок: https://jsfiddle.net/u7ab3ezo/4/

Но теперь на картинку нужно навешивать бейджик со скидкой в правый верхний угол, цену по низу и прочее. Делать это нужно именно по границам картинки. Для этого пробуем обернуть картинку в `inline-block` с `position: relative`: https://jsfiddle.net/u7ab3ezo/5/

В Хроме получается как надо:
[image: Хром]

В Firefox этот оборачивающий инлайн-блок (синий) разуплотняется так, как если бы картинка не масштабировалась:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если подергать ширину экрана то в Firefox все совсем плохо, картинку улетает за границы экрана вообще. Справедливости ради скажу, что в хроме тоже проступает синий фон при изменении размеров окна, но при обновлении/открытии страницы тем не менее все хорошо.

Пробовал оборачивать в inline-flex, в table - не помогает. Помогает оборачивать в inline, но тогда синяя область получается не по высоте картинки, а по строке line-height и в верхние углы уже ничего не закинуть.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли добить этот вариант как-то? Может быть можно обернуть картинку инлайном, который будет в 100% высоты картинки? Или обертку как-то абсолютно спозиционировать?

**UPD1:** В итоге карточка у меня должна выглядеть так. Там более сложные обсчеты пропорциональности, более сложное позиционирование от отступов, но внутри лежит проблема описанная выше.
[image: task]

**UPD2:** Упрощенный и рабочий вариант этой обертки: https://jsfiddle.net/0v8whtrf/
В этом случае Firefox себя ведет так же как и остальные браузеры, тупит только при ресайзе. При открытии страницы - он молодец. Проблемы начинаются, когда я помещаю эту штука в какой-нибудь экстримальный контентекст типа пропорциональной плитки.

Comment: ваш `preview-wrap` и в других браузерах работает кривовато, потому что они с картинкой живут разными жизнями, думаю лучше сделать другой вариант, но для этого нужно более подробное описание что из себя представляет скидка и как вы её планируете выводить, можно попробовать через псевдоэлемент `after` у изображения сделать

Comment: Добавил реальную картинку в вопрос. Скидка и цена - я хотел их через position: absolute; разбрасывать по углам обертки и для этого мне нужно, чтобы обертка схлопывалась по границам изображения.

Comment: Это не то? https://jsfiddle.net/hrxdmo18/
Зачем там вообще position: absolute?

Comment: К сожалению нет. Мне нужно, чтобы сама карточка тянулась с сохранением пропорции от ширины. Картинка внутри должна так же тянуться с сохранением пропорции, но уже от высоты. Вот так: 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22619948/tiles.mov

Comment: Абсолют нужен потому что координаты при абсолюте работают от padding edge, а вертикальный паддинг, чуть ли не единственный способ заставить что-то в верстке сохранять пропорцию. на этом я в самом начале вопроса остановился. Первая ссылка на фиддл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Продвинулся в варианте с `display: inline;`

Если обернуть картинку в inline, то проблема с разуплотнением решается:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но инлайн по высоте не охватывает картинку. Но с другой стороны вертикальный паддинг не влияет на положение инлайна и его можно вытянуть вверх в процентах от родителя! Сбрасываем высоту инлайна в ноль через `font-size: 0;` и задаем `padding-top: 50%;` И получается то, что нужно. Скидку теперь можно абсолютом:

https://jsfiddle.net/u7ab3ezo/7/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]